# Is the # delimiter allways introducing the fragment part of an URI?

Tags: http, url, uri

Is the # delimiter allways introducing the fragment part of an URI?
Or are there any exceptions from the rule, that the # is introducing the fragment part of an URI?

As an example i have the following two URIs:

```
http://example.com/client/index.html#/document/1234567

http://example.com/client/#/document/1234567
```

Is the # in both cases introducing the fragment part?
Or is the # in the second URI still part off the URI path segment, because it is preceded by a slash?

Answer (score 0):

It always starts the fragment identifier. See RFC 3986.